# Execute code after page is fully loaded using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried for several hours to get the following code working. 
The code should be paused until the page is loaded. The problem that I'm encountering is that the AJAX is executing asynchronously.  How would I force the code to wait before executing?

```
var i = 1;
function On_Success(){

    i = i+1;
    if(i<=10){

    $('<div id="p'+i+'">b</div>').replaceAll('#b'); 
    $('#p'+i).load('tabelle.html');
    //here shoul be waited, til the page is loaded
    On_Success();
    };
    };

    function knopf(){
    $('body').append('<div id="p'+i+'">a</div>');
    $('#p'+i).load('tabelle.html'); 
    On_Success();
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accepts a callback that runs when loading is complete; you can use this instead of the more verbose [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, which will require you to write additional code to populate your element.

```
jQuery("#p", i).load("tabelle.html", function() {   
   //code to run when tabelle.html has finished loading
});
```

Change your code to the following. It should work:

```
var i = 1;

function On_Success() {

    i = i + 1;
    if (i <= 10) {
        $('<div id="p' + i + '">b</div>').replaceAll('#b');
        $('#p' + i).load('tabelle.html', On_Success);        
    };
};

function knopf() {
    $('body').append('<div id="p' + i + '">a</div>');
    $('#p' + i).load('tabelle.html', On_Success);
};
```

On another note, is it absolutely necessary that you should wait for one load to complete before populating the other divs? Why can't you do something like this:

```
function On_Success() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 11) {
        $('<div id="p' + i + '">b</div>').replaceAll('#b');
        $('#p' + i).load('tabelle.html');        
    };
};
```

Also, I'm not sure what the `knopf` function is doing. What should the value of `i` be in that function? How are you calling your code?

Comment: The original question asked for "page load" not for the load function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I got stil the same problem, that the code goes on, without waiting

Comment: Now it´s working, I had remove the "()" after the On_Success call, do you know why?

Comment: @nadeshchda The reason is that `load` accepts a callback. When you add a `()` after `On_Success`, it actually calls the function. What you want to do is pass a reference instead, which is what you're doing when you omit the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

Both Ajax and load have an on `successs` function that can be run when the response is fully returned.

```
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: function(html){
                 //do stuff here
                 },
        error: handleAjaxErrors

    });
```

If you want to use load, there is a success callback as well:

```
$("#myDiv").load('/ajax/data/get', function() {
  //do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The load function has a success handler:

```
$('#p'+i).load('tabelle.html', function() {
  On_Success();
});
```

The success handler is only called after the ajax call completes successfully, and after the provided content has been added to the DOM.

You can see full documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you also want to capture error conditions on the client you will need to use the full `$.ajax` call as per @Chris's answer.